# How to easily create stadium tribunes?

Tags: modifiers

How to make stadium tribunes as fast as possible using modifiers and use one global texture as base to all tribunes with no UV maps?
Thanks.

---

[image]
Search on google: bunyodkor stadium

Comment: just make a section, texture it and use an array modifier and a curve modifier to make the circular shape of the stadium.

Comment: Hi. I know this method. Ok. Anyway I'll try again with this method.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, you can make a fully procedural tribune in just 3 steps.
Use the *Screw modifier* and the *Mapping node*.

No UV unwrapping. All modifiers still editable.

[image]

1. Create a profile and use the *Screw modifier* to make it round.
2. Create your image texture
3. Use the *Mapping node* to position it on your tribune.

*Create a tribune profile and add the Screw Modifier.*
[image]

*Adjust your texture position using the Mapping Node.*
[image]

*You're done.*

Comment: But how to make this roof?